# Existing 'list + filter' for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, user-interface

I am designing an application for Windows Phone 7, and I want to create a UI element where a user can select an item from a large list, by using a text search.  Are there any existing controls that provide something like this?

I have found [an example](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls.aspx#listpicker) of something that does what I want, minus the text search.

Alternatively, is there some sort of other control that provides similar usability -- allowing a user to select an item from a list, but providing some way to narrow it down?

Edit:

Is there a list of built-in WP7 controls with documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for an AutoCompleteBox - http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Data-Binding-the-Windows-Phone-Toolkit-AutoCompleteBox